# Options for header in raw byte file

Tags: c#, .net, file, header

I have a large raw data file (up to 1GB) which contains raw samples from a USB data logger.

I need to store extra information relating to the file (sample rate, description, trigger point, last seek position etc) and was looking into adding this as a some sort of header.

The header file should ideally be human readable and flexible so I've so far ruled out some sort of binary serialization into a header.

I also want to avoid two separate files as they could end up separated when copied or backed up. I remembered somebody telling me that newer *.*x Microsoft Office documents are actually a number of files in a zip. Is there a simple way to achieve this? Could I still keep the quick seek times to the raw file?

**Update**

I started using the binary serializer and found it to be a pain. I ended up using the xml serializer as I'm more comfortable using it.
I reserve some space at the start of the files for the xml. Simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say you want to make the header human readable, this suggests opening the file in a text editor.  Do you really want to do this considering the file size and (I'm assuming), the remainder of the file being non-human readable binary data?  If it is, just write the text header data to the start of the binary file - it will be visible when the file is opened but, of course, the remainder of the file will look like garbage.

You could create an uncompressed ZIP archive, which *may* allow you to seek directly to the binary data.  See this for information on creating a ZIP archive: http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2007/10/25/creating-zip-archives-in-net-without-an-external-library-like-sharpziplib.aspx